# I Installed The Unarchiver from the App Store - where should it be?

Tags: install, mac-appstore

I'm a long-time The Unarchiver user. I noticed today that it can be installed and package-controlled by the App Store.

I'm a total App Store novice.

Normally The Unarchiver sits in /Applications/Utilities/. I didn't uninstall The Unarchiver before I installed it from the App Store.

Is there a way of determining that the version of The Unarchiver in /Applications/Utilities/ is the one from the App Store? Further, is there a way *in the App Store* to see all my software installed via the App Store at a glance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Store apps end up in `/Applications`.

I'd uninstall all copies of The Unarchiver using something like TrashMe and then reinstall via the App Store if it's the App Store release that you really want. The App Store's ability to upgrade non-App Store purchased software is hit and miss.

Comment: It hasn't been put in /Applications. In fact, I've taken another look at the App Store and it's asking me if I want to install The Unarchiver. I assume this means it isn't installed already (from the App Store). I'll try nuking my current installation of The Unarchiver and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I nuked the current install and tried again. Now The Unarchiver is sitting in /Applications. Thanks for your help Ian.